# Is TortoiseGit ready for prime time yet?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I'm a big fan of the simplicity of TortoiseSVN. I also am interested in digging into git, and think it would make a good fit for an upcoming project. However, a strictly command-line based app can be a little intimidating. I've followed the [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) project for a little while, and it looks like they are past 1.0.

Is there anyone using it in the wild right now? How's it working out? Does it let you use all of the features in git well?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### YES, it's ready!

TortoiseGit has come a long way since 2009.
And now Microsoft Windows has the best graphical interface to git ;-)

It's especially nice for people that used TortoiseSVN, because it uses familiar dialogs and terminology. Like "Revert.." instead of "Reset / Checkout" or that it abstracts away the "index" in a single (commit) dialog.

Of course there is still room for improvement, mainly because most commands are forwarded to the commandline version, which doesn't give an optimal visualisation.

Answer (score 7):

So far I'm using TortoiseGit 1.0.2.0 just for file status indication in explorer, and sometimes it just doesn't show the icons anymore for a given project (I didn't figure out yet what is the patterns that leads to that behavior).

IMHO in the long term it's better to learn to use git commands directly.

**UPDATE**

If TortoiseGit is not showing the file status icons, then delete the **index_cached.igit** file inside your **.git** folder.

Answer (score 6):

TortoiseGit offers many advantages over the command line git.  I've been using it and I think it's great and have recommended it to the other developers I work with.

And the ammount of 'voodo' was minimal compared to what I had to do to install and get git running on my Centos server.

Answer (score 3):

[SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) is coming along nicely, but it is in a *very* early stage of development. I'm actively using SmartCVS at the moment but migrating to git slowly. If SmartCVS and SmartSVN are anything to go by, it's going to be a good move on Syntevo's part.

But, as alexandrul said I think you should take the time to learn the command line tools as well.

(Just my opinion - I've no connection with Syntevo apart from being a happy customer!)

Comment: I was about to download SmartGit, but found these two license provisions:

"3.3 [... The licensor grants the right] to have the SOFTWARE used

    * on a random number of single-user computers or on a central server or via terminal server clients
    * simultaneously by a random number of users,

[...]"

Random number of users?  Amusing...  I presume they mean "arbitrary."
But the dealbreaker was:

"8 Language

In case of a translation of these provisions only the German version will be valid."

So...  I'm not even agreeing to what I just read?
I can't agree to what I can't understand!

Comment: @mskfisher. You READ terms and conditions?! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Oct2010 Note:** My (below) answer is more than a year old now.  Consider it historical :-).  I have no idea how TortoiseGit is faring lately.

---

Unless you're prepared for pain or failure, it's not ready for primetime.  They've yet to add detailed installation instructions or descriptive error messages, and if you accept msysgit and TortoiseGit defaults it will not work until further voodoo is performed.  It's not obvious to me what that entails.

**Update:** I finally got TortoiseGit to work on one of my two systems.  I ended up going into a cmd console and trying to run git.exe without the msys environment.. and this led me to discover that git.exe couldn't find libcurl-4.dll.  Added my msysgit\mingw\bin dir to the system Path to ensure that it would be found (along with a couple other related paths which I'd already added), and it finally worked.  If the "Check now" button in the TortoiseGit settings doesn't display a version, then you can bet that the dll isn't being found.  There really ought to be an error for that - and this is a reason why I say it's not ready.

Comment: I've been using it for a year without any of these problems.

Answer (score 3):

Git is ready for primetime, and if you go with TortoiseGit at least you will have a great set of tools to fall back on in case weird things happen.

imho weird things always happen with VCSs, and git does a great job of reducing that frequency.

Comment: GIt in itself is ALREADY prime-time.  It's a matter of having GUI tools on windows that can encapsulate Git's functionality.  Which to be honest - once you get to used to the command line, it's like crack - you feel lost without it.

Comment: @MunkiPhD... right, that is what I was trying to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favourite bit from the SmartGit license:

3.2 The SOFTWARE must not be used if its use may result in injuries of life, body, health of human beings or injuries of animals or ecological damages (e.g. no use for atomic reactors, weapons and medical appliances).

Are they serious??

Comment: yes, but they are just saying don’t sue us if it all goes wrong.  I think you will be OK provided git is only used to help write the software rather then as part of the live system.